# How to make a vector PDF searchable?

Tags: pdf, ocr

My workflow includes making figures in Inkscape, which are then converted to PDF and included into LaTeX documents. In these figures, I often have to include mathematical formulas. For that, I use [TexText](https://inkscape.org/%7Ejcwinkler/%E2%98%85textext). For font consistency and simplicity, when I want to add some plain text to my figure, I also use TexText. When the resulting SVG is converted to PDF, the TexText-generated text is not searchable.

**How can I make a PDF from the SVG such that it is searchable while remaining a vector PDF?**

I know I could rasterize the figure and then use e.g. [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc) to create a searchable PDF. But the resulting PDF will of course contain a rasterized version of my figure. I would like the figure itself to remain vector graphics.

I am guessing there has to be a way that would go something like this: indeed rasterize the PDF and use Tesseract to extract the text. But then take the output of Tesseract and somehow add it to the original vector PDF. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ghostscript's pdfwrite device will, if run using a Ghostscript binary built to include Tesseract, use OCR to build a ToUnicode CMap for fonts. Optionally for all fonts or only for fonts which lack a ToUnicode Cmap. This is a new feature, and I've no idea how well it will work with mathematical formulae, I'm guessing not terribly well. You could give it a try. You will need to ensure you are using a recent version of Ghostscript and that the binary has been built to include Tesseract (and Leptonica). NB this assumes the text is still text, not vector linework!

Comment: @KenS Math is really not that important to OCR—it's the regular text (which was also rendered by TexText) that mostly concerns me. So how would this work? Say I have a vector PDF, which was generated from SVG. What do I do next?

Comment: @KenS I did find [these instructions](https://ghostscript.com/blog/ocr.html). But when I download the testing binary for `gs 9.55` [here](https://ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html) and run it on `zlib.3.pdf` (which I downloaded), I get the following error: `Error: /syntaxerror in /----nostringval----`. The downloaded binary is able to perform other operations, e.g. extract pages from a pdf file.

Comment: Well that works for me. You don;t say what OS you are using, so its hard to test any further. However, since you have an answer, I won't poke any further.

Comment: @KenS kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a question that is directly relevant to mine was answered on another StackExchange, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/679979/copy-pdf-text-layer-to-another-pdf). The script that answers my actual question is `svgToSearchablePDF.sh`, and I post it below. It uses, as the key element, the script `pdf-merge-text.sh` from [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1608235) to that other question. For completeness, I will repost `pdf-merge-text.sh` in this answer.

**The solution**

Note that perhaps you will need to magnify the SVG file before converting it to a searchable PDF: larger image sizes help the OCR process. To magnify, in Inkscape, select the entire image, then go to `Object` -> `Transform…` . In the `Transform` tab, select `Scale`. Then select 'Scale proportionally', and finally, in either 'Width' or 'Height', enter something like '300' (make sure `%` is selected in the menu immediately to the right of the 'Width' field). Next, `File`->`Document Properties…`. In the 'Document Properties' tab, under `Custom size`, click on `Resize page to content`. Make sure that either *nothing* is selected or else that the *entire* image is selected. Then click the button 'Resize page to drawing or selection'. Save the SVG.

The script `svgToSearchablePDF.sh` uses an SVG file as input and produces a searchable vector PDF file as output. It is assumed that all of the following are installed: [`Tesseract`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc), `Inkscape`, and `Ghostscript`.

For example, assume that we used Inkscape to create the file `mygraphics.svg`. Then the following command will produce a searchable PDF file `mygraphics.pdf`:

```
svgToSearchablePDF.sh mygraphics.svg
```

**The scripts**

First, `svgToSearchablePDF.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"

inkscape ${filename%.*}.svg -o ${filename%.*}_auxfile.png
inkscape ${filename%.*}.svg -o ${filename%.*}_auxfileVCT.pdf
tesseract ${filename%.*}_auxfile.png ${filename%.*}_auxfileTXT -l eng pdf
pdf-merge-text.sh ${filename%.*}_auxfileTXT.pdf ${filename%.*}_auxfileVCT.pdf ${filename%.*}.pdf


rm -f ${filename%.*}_auxfile.png ${filename%.*}_auxfileVCT.pdf ${filename%.*}_auxfileTXT.pdf
```

As I said, that script uses the script `pdf-merge-text.sh` from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1608235). For completeness, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

pdf_merge_text() {
    local txtpdf; txtpdf="$1"
    local imgpdf; imgpdf="$2"
    local outpdf; outpdf="${3--}"
    if [ "-" != "${txtpdf}" ] && [ ! -f "${txtpdf}" ]; then echo "error: text PDF does not exist: ${txtpdf}" 1>&2; return 1; fi
    if [ "-" != "${imgpdf}" ] && [ ! -f "${imgpdf}" ]; then echo "error: image PDF does not exist: ${imgpdf}" 1>&2; return 1; fi
    if [ "-" != "${outpdf}" ] && [ -e "${outpdf}" ]; then echo "error: not overwriting existing output file: ${outpdf}" 1>&2; return 1; fi
    (
        local txtonlypdf; txtonlypdf="$(TMPDIR=. mktemp --suffix=.pdf)"
        trap "rm -f -- '${txtonlypdf//'/'\\''}'" EXIT
        gs -o "${txtonlypdf}" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERIMAGE "${txtpdf}"
        pdftk "${txtonlypdf}" multistamp "${imgpdf}" output "${outpdf}"
    )
}

pdf_merge_text "$@"
```